# Pass an functor object to constructor of templated class

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, stl, functor

Imagine we have a template class. Something like this

```
template<typename T>
class MyTemplateClass {
private: 
    T _v1, _v2;
public: 
    MyTemplateClass(T v1, T v2)
    {
        _v1 = v1;
        _v2 = v2;
    }
    bool Act()
    {
        return _v1 > _v2;
    }
}; 

//usage
MyTemplateClass<int> test(1, 2);
std::cout << test.Act() << std::endl;
```

now we want to pass a functor object / function pointer / lambda to his constructor so that we can use it.

I've tried something like this, but got runtime-error

```
template<typename T, typename F>
class MyTemplateClass {
private: 
    T _v1, _v2;
    const F& _func;
public: 
    MyTemplateClass(T v1, T v2, F functor)
        :_func(functor)
    {
        _v1 = v1;
        _v2 = v2;
    }
    bool Act()
    {
        return _func(_v1, _v2);
    }
}; 

bool isGreater(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;
} 


//later
    MyTemplateClass<int, std::function<bool(int, int)>> test(1, 2, isGreater);
    std::cout << test.Act() << std::endl;
```

so how could I achieve this functionality? Is there any way to make this working without using std::function and without passing typename for my functor object?
I would like to use it this way

```
MyTemplateClass<int> test(1, 2, isGreater);
```

Comment: Depending on your compiler and version of it, [it might be possible to do what you want](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). If you can enable C++17 mode then try it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it will copy the object and store the object despite the const&? If yes, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher It won't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, i haven't. I can use c++11 only. And it would be good not to use std::function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried something like this, but got runtime-error

As [Matthieu Brucher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266772/matthieu-brucher) pointed out [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54325937/4342498) you can't store `_func` as a reference since the object you bind the reference to dies at the end of the constructor call.  Changing to storing `_func` by value will fix that.

> Is there any way to make this working without using std::function and without passing typename for my functor object? I would like to use it this way
>
> ```
> MyTemplateClass<int> test(1, 2, isGreater);
> ```

This is actually pretty easy to do.  You'll still have to use a `std::function` as the storage type and constructor parameter type but won't have to specify it.  Utilizing a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) we can specify the predicate type in terms of the type of the class members.  That gives us

```
using predicate = std::function<bool(T, T)>;
```

and after adding it to the class we can rework it to be

```
template<typename T>
class MyTemplateClass {
public:
    using predicate = std::function<bool(T, T)>;
    MyTemplateClass(T v1, T v2, predicate functor)
        :_func(std::move(functor))
    {
        _v1 = v1;
        _v2 = v2;
    }
    bool Act()
    {
        return _func(_v1, _v2);
    }
private: 
    T _v1, _v2;
    predicate _func;
};
```

Which can be used now like

```
int main()
{
    MyTemplateClass<int> test(1, 2, isGreater);
    std::cout << test.Act() << std::endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this is not going to work because of the reference on a temporary object (`functor`):

```
const F& _func;
public: 
    MyTemplateClass(T v1, T v2, F functor)
    :_func(functor)
```

Store the object:

```
F _func;
public: 
    MyTemplateClass(T v1, T v2, F functor)
    :_func(std::move(functor))
```

Or in some cases where you know the lifetime of the object, pass it as const&:

```
MyTemplateClass(T v1, T v2, const F& functor)
```

Comment: Specifically, your `const F& _func;` is referring to the `functor` parameter of the constructor, which no longer exists after the construction is finished.

Comment: @L.F. That's what I thought, added a clarification in my answer.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher thanks, my silly mistake. Storing the object is working. But what about not using std::function in template args?

Comment: You can use `bool(*)(int, int)` a the template argument, storing a pointer to the function.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher but this won't work for functors, right?

Comment: No, it cannot. If you pass a lambda, a functor... you need `std::function`. If you have a single function, then you can use a pointer.